# Responsive recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I try to practice with recharts and create histograms with bar chart. It seems to work but I am having difficulty with the responsive on mobile. This is is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';

import { BarChart, Bar, CartesianGrid, Legend, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis } from "recharts";

import { Card, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: '20px 30px',
    marginBottom: '50px',
    padding: '20px 20px'
  },
  barChart: {
    border: '2px solid red',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  barChartbis: {
    border: '2px solid pink',
  }
}));

const Test = ({className, staticContext, ...rest}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const data = [
    { name: "1", consoles: 200 },
    { name: "2", consoles: 150 },
    { name: "3", consoles: 100 },
    { name: "4", consoles: 50 },
  ];

  return (
        <Card
          className={classes.root}
          elevation={2}
          {...rest}
        >
          <div className={classes.barChart}>
           <BarChart className={classes.barChartbis}
            width={600}
            height={400}
            data={data}
            margin={{
              top: 20,
              right: 20,
              left: 20,
              bottom: 20
            }}
            barSize={20}
          >
            <XAxis
              tick={{ fontSize: '0.9em' }}
              padding={{ left: 10, right: 10 }}
              dataKey="name"
            />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <Bar dataKey="consoles" fill="var(--blue-color)" background={{ fill: "#eee" }} />
          </BarChart>
        </div>
        </Card>
  )
}

export default Test;
```

Here are some results with screenshots

[image]

[image]

I think this problem is on BarChart but I can't change width and height

Answer (score 1):

To have a responsive chart using recharts, you just need to put the selected chart inside the `ResponsiveContainer` component, that recharts gives out, like the following:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width={700} height="80%">
  <AreaChart data={data} margin={{ top: 20, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}> // <-- A random chart from recharts
    <XAxis dataKey="name" />
    <YAxis />
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
  </AreaChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Where in the `ResponsiveContainer` props, you could have the width set to a percentage of the window, like `width='80%'` or a static value if you don't want it to change at all.